# LTE Attach procedure and android

Tags: android, gprs

What happens in Android when an LTE attach happens? 
ConnectivityManager class tells about monitoring the network connections like, WIFI, UMTS etc. but not LTE. Also, it doesn't specifies a way to extract information from the Attach procedure that happens, it can be an LTE attach or a GPRS attach.
When an attach procedure happens, a lot of information is passed to the mobile terminal, like the APNs, the proxy address etc. How do I extract that information to use in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is supplied by the OEMs. They set in SystemProperties and the information can be accessed using, SystemProperties.get("net.pdp0.ipv6.pcscf"); or something similar, depending under what name the value is being set by the OEM.